# How to Prevent a Hacker From Causing Damage if Connected to the Same Router

Tags: wifi, router

While using a router that I do not own, and suspect high odds of malicious users' concurrently connecting to it, how can I prevent them from causing any damage to me (injecting malware, stealing information, passwords or otherwise) while using said router?
Whether in university, public cafe etc'

Answer (score 3):

> ... hacker somehow has access to your router, and you don't have access to the router ...

*I'm interpreting this as having no access at all, i.e. specifically no physical access and thus no way to reset the router.* In this case
you are basically asking how to protect your device if your internet access is done through an untrusted router. This is a similar scenario to using a public WiFi hotspot, which should not be considered trusted too.

In this case use a VPN, so that the attacker on the router cannot sniff and modify your traffic. Also use a firewall on your local device, so that incoming connections are not accepted. With windows this could be done by selecting "public" as the type of the network you connect to.

Comment: +1.  '*use a firewall on your local device, so that [all] incoming connections are not accepted*' is sound advice, when using your device on any network that you don't have full control over.

Comment: I would say that it's indeed the equivalent of using a public hotspot while assuming high odds of at least one malicious user connected to it as well.
So it's not possible for the hacker to "inject" malware through the router by knowing the private IP addresses of other devices connected to that public router?

Comment: @CodingMonk: __Once__ the VPN is __properly__ established, the hacker can only block the VPN. But there is a window of opportunity before it gets established, for example with a malicious captive portal. And not all VPN actually work properly, i.e. things like DNS leak combined with direct LAN access might lead to accessing a attacker controlled system in the local network instead of the real system. To get some ideas see [this talk](https://i.blackhat.com/USA-20/Thursday/us-20-vanderWalt-Virtually-Private-Networks.pdf) from Blackhat 2020.